# Logstash syslog configuration example displays with some fields missing

Tags: syslog, logstash-configuration

I tried the Logstash syslog example given in [ELK page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/config-examples.html) by making a slight change in *logstash-syslog.conf* from

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 5000
    type => syslog
  }
  udp {
    port => 5000
    type => syslog
  }
}
```

to

```
input {
  stdin { }
}
```

and tried the given example but the output has only message, @version, @timestamp and host, But I also need

```
   "received_at"
   "received_from" 
   "syslog_severity_code"
   "syslog_facility_code"
   "syslog_facility" 
   "syslog_severity"
```

what have I done wrong? Can somebody help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide your syslog example?

Comment: It's the same as given in ELK Page link I have provided in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the mistake. It doesn't work that way with `stdin{}`.May be it needs an input from a client.
When I input the log with telnet client it works fine.